# Neo4j - Performance issue with Data Migration

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

we are facing performance issue with migrating the data from MS-SQL db to Neo4j. We tried uploading 1M+ records (Nodes) and established relationship between them, queries are executed separately for Node and Relationship creation (through java) on below mentioned system configuration but the process took quite longer (more than a day), so is there any process we should do for make it much faster and better, since this kind of time delay can't be accepted at production environment.

System Configuration:

```
Core: 2 
Memory: 4 GB
```

Comment: I think we need more details on what you did. What Cypher were you using? Did you use the transactional endpoint? REST or embedded?

Comment: @WesFreeman using "Embedded" and Neo4j-Cypher version 1.9.5

Comment: What cypher queries, I meant. Are you using transactions?

Comment: @WesFreeman I Couldn;t understand the "Transaction" here.. i used Create, Match Clause and queries to establish relationship

Comment: You can wrap Cypher in a transaction and do multiple statements at once. Usually, simply doing 1000 at a time gives me a performance boost of 3-4x.

Comment: Hi now i tried using native java to create node and relationship, now it is 80% faster than my previous exercise which has cypher query. :-)